# Do we have pool of objects for wrapper classes too?

Tags: java, string, class, wrapper

I would like to clarify few of queries. As i know Wrapper classes are final too and immutable. So do they have pool of objects just like String class did? and also are there mutable versions for Wrapper classes? String class has mutable versions like StringBuilder and StringBuffer.

Comment: It's not quite clear what kind of Wrapper classes you refer to. Could you add some reference?

Comment: @ralfstx: i mean Wrappers classes like Integer,Double and Character

Comment: @sotorios: Sry thats a typo.. I want to ask if there are any mutable versions for other Wrappers classes just like String did.

Answer (score 6):

Some wrapper classes (for example Long and Integer) have a cache for some values (for Integer and Long, the cache is for values between -128 and 127), which behaves similarly to the String pool, but unlike the String pool it is constant, so adding new objects to it is not possible.

As for your second question, I'm assuming it's a typo and you meant to ask if the wrapper classes have **mutable** versions like String has StringBuilder. The answer is no.

Comment: `AtomicBoolean`, `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong` can be used as mutable versions of the wrapper classes, although this is not their primary purpose and there's no auto-boxing for them.

Comment: @ Eran : What about Character wrapper class? do we have cache or constant pool for Character wrapper class too?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to elaborate on cache part that Eran has mentioned in his answer. This will also answer op's question that he has asked in comments.

1. Cached instances exist for the wrapper Boolean, Byte, Short,
   Integer, Long, Character class.
2. In the case of the Boolean class, the cached instances are
   accessible directly because only two exist: static constants Boolean.TRUE 
   and Boolean.FALSE.
3. The Character class caches instances with values from 0 to 127.
4. The Byte, Short, Integer, and Long cache instances for value -127 to
   128.
5. No cached instances exist for the Float and Double wrapper classes.

If you request an object of any of these classes, from this range, the valueOf() method returns a reference to a predefined object: otherwise, it creates a new object and returns its reference.

```
Example :- 

Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
Integer i2 = new Integer(10);

Integer i3 = Integer.valueOf(10);
Integer i4 = Integer.valueOf(10);

Integer i5 = 10; // Autoboxing, internally autoboxing uses valueOf() method.
Integer i6 = 10;

System.out.println(i1 == i2);
System.out.println(i3 == i4);
System.out.println(i4 == i5);
System.out.println(i5 == i6);


O/P :- 
false
true - result is true because valueOf() returns a cached copy.
true
true
```